# Buffon's Needle problem in a grid intersecting two lines

Tags: calculus, probability

I have been trying to solve the case of Buffon's needle problem in a grid where it intersects both of the lines. I have been able to solve the case of intersecting one of the two lines in grid.
Specifications:
The dimensions of rectangle: axb
The length of needle: l and
$l\leq (a,b)$
I discovered some solutions using double and triple integrals. However, I am not able understand them properly because of lack of any form of explaination.
Any form of assistance would be very helpful :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! As of now, your question seems to take some effort to understand. Please expand (in a few paragraphs) more on the problem, so that people will be able to easily understand your problem.

Comment: You could say where you found these solutions so that others could look at them. It is very hard to explain something when you don't know what you are supposed to explain.

Comment: What is $(a,b)$? It must be some number you can compare with $l$. Is it the minimum of $a$ and $b$, or some other number you can compute from $a$ and $b$?

Comment: When you say "grid" do you mean there is a set of uniformly spaced parallel lines in one direction, and another set of uniformly spaced parallel lines perpendicular to the first set? When you say "intersects both of the lines" do you mean intersecting one line from each parallel set? Is the $a\times b$ rectangle the rectangle enclosed by pairs of adjacent lines in each direction?

Comment: a and b are the dimensions of the grid which is the length and the width respectively. and yes when i say grid that is exactly what i mean sorry for any form of misunderstanding